# TinyMapper: How to map two different property name

Tags: c#, tinymapper

Let's say i have property like Id and in other class property name is ShipmentId, I want to map Id with ShipmentId. 
Is this possible with **TinyMapper**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be possible like so:

```
TinyMapper.Bind<SourceClass, TargetClass>(config =>
{
    config.Bind(source => source.Id, target => target.ShipmentId);
});
```

Comment: Is there any attribute which i can decorate to source as destination property mapping?

Comment: yes you can. In your SourceClass you can decorate the properties like described in this test: https://github.com/TinyMapper/TinyMapper/blob/master/Source/UnitTests/Mappings/Attributes/MappingWithAttributesTests.cs